# load xml file into variable

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml format that I need to load into a variable, initially I had the xml input directly, but do to php issues I have the .xml in a seperate file.

```
Originally


            var labelXml = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">\
            <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
            <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
            <Id>Address</Id>\
            <PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
            <DrawCommands>\
            <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270"/>\
            </DrawCommands>\
            <ObjectInfo>\
            <BarcodeObject>\
            <Name>BARCODE</Name>\
            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/>\
            <BackColor Alpha="255" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255"/>\
            <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
            <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
            <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
            <IsVariable>False</IsVariable>\
            <Text>*E200001*</Text>\
            <Type>Code39</Type>\
            <Size>Medium</Size>\
            <TextPosition>Bottom</TextPosition>\
            <TextFont Family="Lucida Grande" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>\
            <CheckSumFont Family="Lucida Grande" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>\
            <TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding>\
            <ECLevel>0</ECLevel>\
            <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
            <QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Right="0" Top="0" Bottom="0"/>\
            </BarcodeObject>\
            <Bounds X="331.2" Y="328.0469" Width="4455.625" Height="1044.844"/>\
            </ObjectInfo>\
            </DieCutLabel>';
```

Now what I have is

```
var labelXml = loadXMLDoc("barcode.xml");
```

however, I get the error "loadxmldoc is undefined" due to browser incompatibility . So does anyone know a way to load the .xml to the variable so that it would have the same format as the original?

```
 function loadXMLDoc(filename)
  {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else // code for IE5 and IE6
    {
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
  xhttp.send();
  return xhttp.responseXML;
  }
```

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: loadXMLDoc("barcode.xml");

Comment: the first one gives you a string, the second one gives you a DOMDocument. if you want a string, `return xhttp.responseText;`

Comment: Note that synchronous AJAX has been deprecated, so you really want to either code a new, async function that uses `xhr.onreadystatechange` with all the readystate/status checks necessary, or use something like [jQuery](https://jquery.com) or [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to load in your data from URL for further handling, rather than thise code. And on an unrelated note, I am very interested in why you need IE5/6 support...